# I want to set limit scrolling to a scrollable panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a scrollable panel like this:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form f2 = new Form();
    f2.Size = new Size(400, 300);
    f2.AutoScroll = false;
    Panel pan = new Panel();
    pan.Size = new Size(600, 100);
    pan.AutoScroll = false;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Text = "B" + (i);
        b.Name = "button_" + (i);
        b.Left = (b.Width + 12) * (i - 1);
        b.Parent = pan;
        pan.Parent = f2;
        f2.Show();
    }
}

private void panel1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        panel1.Top += e.Delta > 0 ? 10 : -10;
        if (panel1.Top > 0) 
            panel1.Top = 0;
        else if (panel1.Top <= panel1.Parent.Height) 
            panel1.Top = panel1.Parent.Height;
        Console.WriteLine("panel2.top:" + panel1.Top);

    }
```

This is the full code of that panel, panel1 = pan...

```
private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    pPt = e.Location;
}
public void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("panel2.top:" + panel1.Top);
    if (e.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left))
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        panel1.Top += e.Y - pPt.Y;
        if (panel1.Top > 0) 
            panel1.Top = 0;
        else if (panel1.Top <= panel1.Parent.Height) 
            panel1.Top = panel1.Parent.Height;
    }
}
```

And you can scroll it by dragging the panel with the mouse but the problem is it looks like this: [image]

And I want to don't go higher than button1 or lower than the last button.

Comment: Can you post the full code of the form?

Comment: Got it. It has to do with restricting the delta - posting you answer

Comment: It's because you are forgetting that mouse wheel events are continuously fired by the mouse, so you need to add logic to ignore them when the panel is at the top or at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Tweak this method: you need to "pin" the panel so it doesn't move below the top and above the bottom - because mouse wheel deltas are events you will continuously receive. You have to manually decide when to ignore them

```
private void panel1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        panel1.Top += e.Delta > 0 ? 10 : -10;

        // tweak this
        if (panel1.Top > 0) panel1.Top = 0;
        else if (panel1.Bottom <= panel1.Parent.Height) panel1.Bottom = panel1.Parent.Height;

        Console.WriteLine("panel2.top:" + panel1.Top);

}
```

Also, the above will work when the panel you are scrolling is "Taller" than the viewport (the form itself). You might need to tweak further when the panel is smaller than the form - so just test a few cases.

You also need to pay attention to the Resize event so your panel has the correct Top property when someone expands the container form.

Comment: Thank that should work, also... I have that mousedown and mousemove so the panel can be scrollable by dragging with mouse but with panel1.Top = 0; looks weird when you try to scroll above the panel.. do you have anything else for this?

Comment: Also... don't you need to calculate the panel1.bottom too?

Comment: This works this way... when i try to scroll below the panel it goes again up... I want it to stand still.

Comment: Like I said, you need to tweak the logic to your needs :) The solution though was that you needed to start discarding mouse wheels to prevent the panel from moving beyond boundaries, and you do that by checking the position of the panel within its container.

Comment: Yeah.. I understand but I couldn't figure out how to do the last thing... I mean when I go too low to stand still at the end of the panel... I tried a lot of things and didn't work

Comment: Can you post a link to your full code on github? (don't post the entire listing here) and I'll be happy to take a look and see.

Comment: I did it.... but another way... anyway here is my link if you still want it: https://github.com/cristicretan/OutfitPick

Answer (score 0):

We can Get or set the upper limit of values of the scrollable range with

> ScrollBar.Maximum Property

An example is as follows.

*The following example assumes that you have created a Form, added a PictureBox to the Form, and added a horizontal HScrollBar and a vertical VScrollBar to the PictureBox. This code example is part of a larger example provided for the ScrollBar class overview.
In this example, the Maximum property is set to the size of the Image plus the size of the scrollbar if it is visible plus an adjustment factor of the size of the LargeChange property.
You must add references to the System.Drawing and System.Windows.Forms namespaces to run this example.*

```
public void SetScrollBarValues()
    {
        //Set the following scrollbar properties:

        //Minimum: Set to 0

        //SmallChange and LargeChange: Per UI guidelines, these must be set
        //    relative to the size of the view that the user sees, not to
        //    the total size including the unseen part.  In this example,
        //    these must be set relative to the picture box, not to the image.

        //Maximum: Calculate in steps:
        //Step 1: The maximum to scroll is the size of the unseen part.
        //Step 2: Add the size of visible scrollbars if necessary.
        //Step 3: Add an adjustment factor of ScrollBar.LargeChange.


        //Configure the horizontal scrollbar
        //---------------------------------------------
        if (this.hScrollBar1.Visible)
        {
            this.hScrollBar1.Minimum = 0;
            this.hScrollBar1.SmallChange = this.pictureBox1.Width / 20;
            this.hScrollBar1.LargeChange = this.pictureBox1.Width / 10;

            this.hScrollBar1.Maximum = this.pictureBox1.Image.Size.Width - pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width;  //step 1

            if (this.vScrollBar1.Visible) //step 2
            {
                this.hScrollBar1.Maximum += this.vScrollBar1.Width;
            }

            this.hScrollBar1.Maximum += this.hScrollBar1.LargeChange; //step 3
        }

        //Configure the vertical scrollbar
        //---------------------------------------------
        if (this.vScrollBar1.Visible)
        {
            this.vScrollBar1.Minimum = 0;
            this.vScrollBar1.SmallChange = this.pictureBox1.Height / 20;
            this.vScrollBar1.LargeChange = this.pictureBox1.Height / 10;

            this.vScrollBar1.Maximum = this.pictureBox1.Image.Size.Height - pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height; //step 1

            if (this.hScrollBar1.Visible) //step 2
            {
                this.vScrollBar1.Maximum += this.hScrollBar1.Height;
            }

            this.vScrollBar1.Maximum += this.vScrollBar1.LargeChange; //step 3
        }
    }
```

Hope you can change the code accordingly to set the maximum scrollable space.:)